# Is it possible for ESlint autofix break my code?

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I ran ESlint (with `prettier` plugin) on my repo and it showed about 700 problems, 600 of them it said it can autofix with the `--fix` flag.

How should I approach this?
Is it safe to autofix or it could break my code and I should do it manually one file at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Functional breaks are possible but highly unlikely. Breaking something related to the Typescript compiler is more likely but instantly spottable and easy to fix/rollback.

Also, it depends on what rules you use; just `eslint:recommended` should be very safe.